# Android silent push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

We think that Android’s push notifications by default are silent notifications and must be the developer who programmatically raise the notification on the screen. Or the push notifications aren’t silent by default?

Today we work using this JSON structure which our app receives from the GCM server.

```
{ 
   "data": 
         {
               “Type” : “2”, 
               “_dId” : “3718829”, 
               “_mId” : “9924012”, 
               “_msg” : “HOLA JVE”, 
               “collapse_key” : “9924012”
          },                                       
   "to" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Is this structure valid for silent notifications or there is a different one ? 
Truly we are pretty lost on this topic. Following this question, anyone have a json structure of an Android push notification with *message* and *title* tags ?

*Other question* : When a silent notification is shown to the user ? When the user open the app or just when the user unlock the phone ?

Answer (score 3):

> *Or the push notifications aren’t silent by default?*

There are two ways that a notification is received in Android, either it's Notification Tray, or you handle it yourself in `onMessageReceived()` depending on which payload you use (`Notification` or `Data`).

Basing from your inquiry (*silent push notification*), I'm guessing you'd prefer the latter, since you'll be able to handle it yourself. As per the [GCM Payload docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#payload):

> Use notifications when you want GCM to handle displaying a notification on your client app’s behalf. **Use data messages when you want your app to handle the display or process the messages on your Android client app**,..

So what you are currently using right now, (a `data` payload) should be fine. However, if you have **both** `notification` and `data` in your payload, you will have to consider your app's status. Referring to this [FCM docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages), for `data` payload:

```
App state   Notification        Data                Both
Foreground  onMessageReceived   onMessageReceived   onMessageReceived
Background  System tray         onMessageReceived   Notification: system tray
                                                    Data: in extras of the intent.
```

---

> *..anyone have a json structure of an Android push notification with message and title tags ?*

As also mentioned in the docs I linked above:

> Data messages have only custom key/value pairs.

So I think it's safe for you to just use keys so long as it's not a reserved word, as mentioned in this [docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json):

> The key should not be a reserved word ("from" or any word starting with "google" or "gcm"). Do not use any of the words defined in this table (such as collapse_key).

---

> *When a silent notification is shown to the user ? When the user open the app or just when the user unlock the phone ?*

I think what I mentioned above pretty much covers this part (*see the table*).

Answer (score 1):

On Android, differently from iOS, the app is responsible for creating and showing the push notification. So yes, you can think of them as silent by default, although you don't exactly have this concept on Android.

What I normally do is, if the notification should not be shown, add a `silent` field. For example:

```
 {
    "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "Will not show this message",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon"
      "silent": "true"
    }
  }
```

And then you can use the silent field to show or not show the notification according to an `if` statement.